# Merge array values in a `foreach` loop

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have two arrays that are inside `foreach` loop, I want to merge them to one key and value.

let the first array "*array1*" inside `foreach`:

```
$array1 = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
```

let the second array "*array2*" inside `foreach`:

```
$array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

Expected output should be as follows:

```
$mergeArray = [0=>['x', 'y', 'z','a', 'b', 'c']];
```

What I have done is the following:

```
$mergeArray = [];

foreach ($customer as $key => $value) {

    $mergeArray[] = $value['items1'];
    $mergeArray[] = $value['items2'];

   echo '<pre>';     
   print_r($mergeArray);
   exit;

}
```

Thanks and welcome all suggestions

Comment: Doesn't `array_merge($array1, $array2)` do what you want?

Comment: @Barmar, i want merge as single key and value as shown $mergeArray

Comment: The array you show is equivalent to `[0 => 'x', 1 => 'y', 2 => 'z', ...]`

Comment: It's not a single key, you just didn't show all the other array keys.

Comment: Did you mean `[0 => ['x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c']]`?

Comment: @Barmar, yes you are wright, i am expecting as [0 => ['x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c']], because i want update database

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_merge`:

```
$mergeArray[] = array_merge($value['item1'], $value['item2']);
```

Also, the `exit` should not be in the loop, that will prevent the loop from repeating.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with  this code

```
   $mergeArray = [];

  foreach ($customer as $key => $value) {

$mergeArray[0] =array_merge ( $value['items1'],  $value['items2']); 

  echo '<pre>';     
  print_r($mergeArray);
  exit; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use a foreach loop at all? Am I missing something?

```
$array1 = array('x', 'y', 'z');

$array2 = array('a', 'b', 'c');

$mergeArray[0] = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
            [3] => a
            [4] => b
            [5] => c
        )

)
```

Comment: You redid the question after I gave my answer. I will edit mine to do what you are now requesting.

Comment: Why the negative rating? I answer the question clearly and have updated it according to new information provided by the OP.